# ORACLE XML values extract as pivot

Tags: xml, oracle, pivot, extract

i would like to know is there any way that i could get out put form xml file as pivot??

my code

```
select t.extract('/S/@ID').getstringval() as s 
FROM
TABLE( 
XMLSEQUENCE( 
(select xmltype('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SERIAL>
<S ID="1E0100057107" />
<S ID="1E0100057108" />
<S ID="1E0100057109" />
<S ID="1E0100057110" />
</SERIAL>').extract( '//S' ) from dual)
))T;
desired output 
S
-------------------------
1E0100057107,1E0100057108,1E0100057109,1E0100057110
```

thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LISTAGG` Function (supports string up to 4000 chars)

```
select LISTAGG(t.extract('/S/@ID').getstringval(),',')  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 1) as s
FROM
TABLE( 
XMLSEQUENCE( 
(select xmltype('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SERIAL>
<S ID="1E0100057107" />
<S ID="1E0100057108" />
<S ID="1E0100057109" />
<S ID="1E0100057110" />
</SERIAL>').extract( '//S' ) from dual)
))T;
```

Or `XMLAGG`

```
select xmlagg(xmlelement(e, t.extract('/S/@ID').getstringval()|| ',')).extract('//text()').extract('//text()')
FROM
TABLE( 
XMLSEQUENCE( 
(select xmltype('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SERIAL>
<S ID="1E0100057107" />
<S ID="1E0100057108" />
<S ID="1E0100057109" />
<S ID="1E0100057110" />
</SERIAL>').extract( '//S' ) from dual)
))T;
```

Comment: hkutluay thank you very much you save my day thanks again its working

Comment: i will select this as my answer within 5 min :)

Comment: this is ok but when xml list contain large amount of (1000 record) data its not working can you give me a solution

Comment: now its ok , for large amount of data xmlargs working fun. thanks for your help